# Двусвязный список на java

Tags: java

```
    public class Node {
  private int element;
  private Node next;

  public int getElement(){
    return element;
  }

  public void setElement(int e){
    element = e;
  }

  public Node getNext() {
    return next;
  }

  public void setNext(Node n) {
    next = n;
  }
}
```

Comment: Я обычный список написала, а двумерный не могу. Не могу понять, как мне передвигать хвост и указатели именно на него.

Comment: вообще то она уже есть написанная в джаве и при желании можно там посмотреть ее реализацию и скопировать себе...

Comment: мне нужно собственная реализация с помощью указателей

Comment: Указателей?? Хочу вас огорчить их: в Java нет.

Comment: в джаве нету указателей =) (trollface)

Comment: И кстати, он не двумерный список. И этот список не сильно отличается в реализации от односвязного.

Comment: Я считаю, что поле next у меня как указатель.

Comment: Правильно считаете, @Ksenia. Хотя все в Java называют это ссылкой, но по сути это все равно указатель (только там не прямо адрес машинной памяти, как в Си).

Comment: @Ksenia, советую не править закрытый вопрос (причем так, что все ответы-комментарии теперь непонятно к чему), а открыть новый, 

и в нем **русскими словами написать, что делает** ***каждый метод*** **и для каких целей нужно** ***каждое поле*** Вашего класса (теперь Node). 

Также опишите, как Вы видите использование этого класса (пример программы с подробными комментариями, создающий экземпляры Node и манипулирующий ими).

Во всех комментариях пишите не только, *что делаем*, но и *с какой целью* делаем это.

--

Подсказываю: для двусвязности к private Node next добавьте еще и ссылку prev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Читать матчасть тут. [Структуры данных в картинках. LinkedList](http://habrahabr.ru/post/127864/).
2. Смотреть исходник, т.е. ваше задание тут. [LinkedList.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6-gate/jdk/file/4eed3d0d3293/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java).

Comment: Вы не могли бы мне хоть часть кода написать, просто у меня проблема именно с хвостом, я не могу их так просто передвинуть.

Comment: Автор кода (по ссылке) хорош. Книги мне его нравятся.

Comment: если честно такое читать даже трудно, temp'ы в глазах рябят

а так по тому что вижу

зачем temphead, temptail?

каким образом head, tail равняются числу? если это объекты

Comment: @Ksenia, head=tail=1; и tail=2; это ни в какие ворота не лезет.

Вы хотите сделать список из 2-х элементов. Почему не написать просто ?

    head = new Element(); head.value = 1;
    tail = head.next = new Element(); tail.value = 2;

--

Но это все по сути неправильно. Создайте класс KseniaList с полями Element head, tail и int count. Такой вот специализированный список.


new KseniaList() будет создавать пустой (с count = 0) список.

в классе Element сделайте поля next, prev и value.

В этом классе делаете KseniaList нужные Вам методы для манипуляции списком . И никаких глобальных переменных